# Webparts Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

I have data in SQLDataReader reference variable. I have to display the data in a gridview or SPGridview in a sharepoint custom webpart.

How do I do it ? Could anybody point me ?

Thank you
Hari

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a great intro tutorial to getting setup with an SPGridView: http://www.reversealchemy.net/2009/05/01/building-a-spgridview-control-part-1-introducing-the-spgridview/

The main difference will be using a SQLDataReader instead of an ObjectDataSource (although I guess you could use a SQLDataReader inside an ObjectDataSource to return a datatable): http://forums.asp.net/p/1095791/1653835.aspx

Answer (score 0):

[This link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b8e86c/pagination-sorting-and-filtering-in-spgridview/)  will help you to work with `SPGridview`